# Process-wide "AssemblyLoad" Event

Tags: .net, events, reflection, appdomain

I can receive events, using the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event, but only for a particular app domain.  If I have appdomains that recursively create more appdomains, I believe my AssemblyLoad event will not work for those "grand-child" appdomains.

How can I be sure to get an AssemblyLoad event triggered, regardless of what appdomain loaded an assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each AD will have to register its own AssemblyLoad event.  You will obviously miss at least the 1st assembly you load into it.  The idea of a "process-side" event is murky, these event handlers cannot share anything since each AD has its own garbage collected heap.  I guess you could serialize info back to the primary AD.

Comment: As a side note, do you happen to know if an assembly load event can "touch" or modify statics in the newly loaded assembly?

Comment: Sure, each AD has its own statics storage area (loader heap).